# How to set child information in the parent container?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react project. A new view requires children information inside a component that belongs to the parent. I wonder if the whole component  architecture needs to be changed, or is there a simpler way. The app header shall contain a select that belongs to the {children}.

Structure

```
<Maincontainer>
  <AppHeader />  //here I need a select box according to the active children
  {children}
</MainContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever such case occurs it is an indication of the need to move the required information up in the component hierarchy. It is no longer a "child information".

In you case you should move it from children's state to `Maincontainer` state. Then pass it down via props to `AppHeader` and / or other children.

You can read more about this technique [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use children as property for the AppHeader?

```
<Maincontainer>
  <AppHeader children={children} />  //here I need a select box according to the active children
  {children}
</MainContainer>
```

Comment: Sure. You might want to read up on how props work. This should make things easier: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html